# How to solve Ax=b with OpenCV cv::SparseMat

Tags: c++, opencv, sparse-matrix, least-squares

As written in title, i want to solve Ax=b. 
When creating A with `cv::Mat` and my needed dimensions of (10 million x 5 million entries) the allocation of this storage will (obviously) fail :-D.
Instead I want to use `cv::SparseMat` cause every row has only two entries (1 or -1) this should be the right way to go.

But how is it possible to solve Ax=b using OpenCV and SparseMat?

With `cv::Mat` this is done using `cv::solve(A,b,x, Solver)` but it wont work (its not a correct input argument of type `cv::InputArray`) with `cv::SparseMat` any ideas how I can solve x using OpenCV (3.1.0)?

Comment: I think (not sure) that openCV doesnt have Ax=b solvers for sparse matrices

Comment: "It does not work" is not a proper problem description or question.

Comment: @knivil: SparseMat is not a possible Input Argument for `cv::solve`; @Ander Biguri: sadly thats what I am guessing, too!

Comment: every row only +1 and -1? does this mean every other element is 0 or is EVERY element +1 or -1? Anyways, I guess there might be an "easier" way than Ax=b to solve that problem, because this looks very special.

Comment: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html

Comment: @Micka only two elements in a row are +1 or -1 and every other element is 0.

Comment: @Micka 2: the eigen lib with the "Solving Sparse Linear Systems" functionality is not included in the OpenCV, is this correct? To my knowlegde some Eigen functionalities are used by OpenCV.

Comment: afaik it is not used by openCV

Comment: It seems like OpenCV has at least `eigen2cv` and `cv2eigen` transformations [link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d0/daf/group__core__eigen.html#gsc.tab=0). And further: to answer my question - it (sadly) can't be done using OpenCV!